# skip single minus or plus signs among integer input

Tags: c++, validation

Recently I needed a simple program to sum all integers occurring on standard input, one integer per line. The input happened to contain some unset lines, containing a single minus ('-') sign, and also some lines with junk characters (to be ignored).

This would be a trivial program, I believed. But as it turned out the single minus signs didn't behave as other bad input. On normal non-integer input the fail flag is set and the bad input remains in the input buffer. But with a single minus (or plus) sign the fail flag is set, but the +/- sign is removed, causing the program to skip the next (valid) integer (causing wrong sum).

I wrote a small test program (below) to analyze the behavior.
Is the above described behavior with +/- signs a bug or a feature?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string s;
  int n;

  while (true)
  {
    n = -4711;
    cin >> n;

    cerr << (cin.bad()  ? "ERROR: badbit is set\n" : "");
    cerr << (cin.fail() ? "ERROR: failbit is set\n" : "");
    cerr << (cin.eof()  ? "ERROR: eofbit is set\n" : "");

    if ( cin.bad() || cin.eof() )
      break;

    if ( cin.fail() )
    {
      cin.clear();
      cin >> s;
      cerr << "ERROR: ignored string '" << s
           << "' (integer is '" << n << "')" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "OK: read integer '" << n << "'" << endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Running the program (with input: "1 asdf 2 - 3 + 4 qwer 5"):

```
~ $ ./a.out
1 asdf 2 - 3 + 4 qwer 5 
OK: read integer '1'
ERROR: failbit is set
ERROR: ignored string 'asdf' (integer is '0')
OK: read integer '2'
ERROR: failbit is set
ERROR: ignored string '3' (integer is '0')
ERROR: failbit is set
ERROR: ignored string '4' (integer is '0')
ERROR: failbit is set
ERROR: ignored string 'qwer' (integer is '0')
OK: read integer '5'
```

(I already solved my original problem by reading strings instead, and using C++11 stoi with exceptions to identify bad input.)

Edit: If anyone is interested in the solution to my original problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int sum = 0;
  string n;

  while ( cin >> n )
  {
    try {
      sum += stoi(n);
      cout << n << endl;
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
      cerr << e.what() << " ERROR: '" << n << "' is not a number." << endl;
    }
  }
  cout << sum << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature. `cin` doesn't know until it has read the space after the '-' that the input is in error. There's no portable way using iostreams to put back more than a single character, and there's no portable way to seek in cin. So it's stuck and has to leave the '-' as read.

There comes a point when reading data that it's better to your own parsing. Read all the data into strings and then parse those strings yourself to determine what is real and what is junk. That way you have full control instead of fighting whatever it is that the iostreams do.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it something like this:

```
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

struct number_only: std::ctype<char> { 
    number_only() : std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {} 

    static mask const *get_table() { 
        static std::vector<mask> rc(table_size, space);

        std::fill_n(&rc['0'], 10, digit);
        return &rc[0]; 
    } 
};

int main() { 
    std::string input("1 asdf 2 - 3 + 4 qwer 5 ");
    std::istringstream x(input);

    // use our ctype facet:
    x.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new number_only));

    // initialize vector from the numbers in the file:
    std::vector<int> numbers((std::istream_iterator<int>(x)), 
                                std::istream_iterator<int>());

    // display what we read:
    std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not the most straightforward solution, but very interesting I must say! (I didn't play with locales before.)

Comment: @kma: I dunno -- the logic in the code you write becomes almost almost ridiculously simple. Consider that this code works, has no (explicit) conditions (if, while, etc.) and is still shorter than the (non-functional) sample in the question.

Comment: Your's is a good solution, it rules out unwanted input at an early stage. Probably very efficient. That's why I think it's interesting to see. If it's straightforward or not is of course very subjective - depend on what you already know I guess.

Comment: Btw, I added my solution to my original problem to the post. It does not buffer all input in a vector which might be of importance. (Jerry's solution can easily be rewritten to avoid the vector and do the sum.)